# How to display data into a table with a button next to it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

This is a picture of what I want to achieve:

[image]

I want to display all categories in a table and add a columns next to it which contains a button. On clicking this button, it should redirect to another page showing more details about that category.

Any idea of how to proceed?

So far this is what I have done:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=NASHIISHEENA;Initial Catalog=HousekeepingPortal_DB;Integrated Security=True");
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Cat_Name from tblCategory",conn);
   conn.Open();
   SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   GridView1.DataSource = dr;
   GridView1.DataBind();
   conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: where is your GridView's HTML ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I cannot give you a full code of what you are trying to achieve, but I will give you the general idea.

First of all - for creating a table you can either use `GridView` or `ListView`. Another option is to use a normal List and than create a `Grid`/`DockPanel` as a DataTemplate of each item. I think this solution is the easiest so I will demonstrate on this.

I'll show you how to implement it using `ListView` and maintain MVVM Architecture. Please note that calling an event like you did is not MVVM-like and I recommend using `Command`s instead.

First you need something on the `ViewModel` which explains what sort of page you are viewing currently and bind it to the actual view. I do not know exactly what  you want so I can't show you actually code of this part.

Than you create a `Command` called `OpenPageCommand`on your `ListView` which gets its item/page/whatever object it needs through the `object` parameter.

As for the `ListBox` part and the command binding:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="150" Content="Show detalils" 
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" 
                                CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name }"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Solutions with `GridView` or `ListView` should be similar. Note that in those cases you probably would need to use `CellTemplate` to put the button in one of the columns.

If you have any questions, please say so in the comments.

Comment: The question is about Asp.Net, not WPF or UWP.